# I can't get current millisecond in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cypress

I can't get updated (current) time as milliseconds below. Even if I reassign the system time inside of the loop, the functionality does not work as I aimed. I'm kinda new about using JavaScript. So I was trying to convert below Java code to JavaScript. What is the problem in my JS code could you help me please?

**My purpose with this function: Make system wait until the value becomes not null**

Current result -> Time difference does not change per given check interval

```
   waitUntilValueComes(value, timeout, checkInterval) {
       let currentTime = new Date().getMilliseconds()
       cy.log('Current time ' + currentTime)
       let diff = new Date().getMilliseconds()- currentTime
       while (timeout > (diff)) {
           cy.log('Date time ' + diff)
           if (value != null) {
               break
           }
           cy.wait(checkInterval)
           diff = new Date().getMilliseconds()- currentTime
       }
   }
```

Java Code that I tried to transform into JS

```
public void waitUntilValueComes(String value, long timeout, long checkInterval) throws InterruptedException {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (timeout > System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime) {
            if (value!= null)
                break;
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(checkInterval));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're getting the `seconds` part of the date by using `Date.getSeconds()`. This can cause unexpected behavior as well, because it's just the seconds, not the timestamp. Instead, you can use [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) to get the milliseconds and then calculate the difference

Comment: Why use `getSeconds` at all?

Comment: I tried also using Date.now(). Behavior is same unfortunately. Somehow date does not change :S @HarunYilmaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Date.now()  Global object and method which gets the current time with milliseconds but in unix  timestamp however its a little inaccurate compared to the 2nd method in firefox browsers as per the MDN Docs

The first method is what you need if you need the time stamp

The second method is the same as the method you used

1. Just assign a new `const newDate = new Date();`
2. Call that const with `.getMilliseconds()` method
3. assign that to a new `const dateMS = newDate.getMilliseconds();`
4. Debug the dateMS variable we just assigned`console.log(dateMS)`;

```js
 const dateNow = Date.now();
console.log("dateNow is:" + dateNow);
//https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

//FOR YOUR OLD METHOD JUST ASSIGN A VARIABLE for the new date
const newDate = new Date();
const dateMS = newDate.getMilliseconds();
console.log("Date in milli seconds is" + dateMS);
```

[W3School JavaScript Date Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)